# Eclipse Jboss, wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, wildfly

I'm currently trying to install JBOSS TOOLS on my Eclipse, but the "selected features" tab is not popping. Anyone had a similar problem?

I cleared the cache, installed eclipse all over again but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have an image of what that's supposed to look like, and what you're seeing instead?